# IEEE Format: sections in separate files create page breaks

Tags: page-breaking, ieeetran

I want to make my paper repository a little more readable, so I like to break sections out into separate .tex documents.  However, this does not seem to play nice with the IEEE format.  How can I get my intro (and subsequent sections) in a separate document and not have a page break before it?

MWE (sorry, just building off their example... super long):

in bare_jrnl.tex:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}


\begin{document}
\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Journals}

\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{M. Shell is with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332 USA e-mail: (see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html).}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{J. Doe and J. Doe are with Anonymous University.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised September 17, 2014.}}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
IEEEtran, journal, \LaTeX, paper, template.
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\include{intro}

\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.



% use section* for acknowledgment
\section*{Acknowledgment}


The authors would like to thank...

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{IEEEhowto:kopka}
H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Michael Shell}
Biography text here.
\end{IEEEbiography}
\end{document}
```

in intro.tex:

```
\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{his} demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE journal papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.8a and later.
I wish you the best of success.

\hfill mds

\hfill September 17, 2014

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here.

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.
```

Comment: Use `\input` instead of `\include`, i.e., write `\input intro` instead of `\include{intro}`. Note that this issue isn't related to the use of the IEEEtran document class.

Comment: See [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246/5764)

Comment: Indeed, what is the difference between the two commands?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include -- turns out someone else had this question.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\input` instead of `\include`. For more, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) .